# Restore Deleted Account in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am wondering whether data can be restored if our google tag manager account is deleted by mistake. 
We have the gmail address which is also the user name of google tag manager.

Comment: This is a question you should ask an Adwords representative if you have one.

Comment: Hi @LothaireRuellan , thanks for your reply.  I know Adwords can help me restore google analytics's account.  Are they also responsible for Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently it's not possible. Maybe you can try to contact with support in some way.

Comment: Hi @mrbubu, thanks for your reply. do you hv any idea about support contact.. i have been searching on Internet for several days, but get no results... :(

Comment: Maybe you should try Send Feedback link in the bottom of any GTM account and describe your problem there.

Answer (score -1):

Data isn't stored in GTM, only managed and fired through this interface. If you are talking about a tag that was deleted from GTM, you will not be collecting data for this tag.

In GA, historical data should still be available in the Google Analytics account, even if the tag is deleted from GTM. No new data will be pushed to the account until a tag is reinstalled in GTM.

In GTM, you can replace this deleted tag and continue collecting data for that property.